# ASP.NET Core MVC: how to implement SOLID principle when creating buisness and Model?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern

I have created an ASP.NET Core MVC project. It has a repository class and a business logic layer.

I have created an interface for the repository class and another for BLL class.

From the controller I am injecting the BLL class, and it accesses the repository to get the data.

So the point I am trying to make here, my controller doesn't know anything about the repository class which is the model class, but it accesses the business class through dependency injection, and the business class accesses the repository class through dependency injection.

So now I am kind of confused. I am thinking, controller should have access to business and repository, both should be injected from the controller. Controller should be getting the data from the repository class and passing it to the BLL. Instead, controllers only access bll and then the bll accesses the repository class.

I like to know what approach to follow which makes more sense and consider good practice. I did try to research but was not able to get the direct answer for my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having top class (the controller) being injected with two other classes (bll and repository) won't necessarily make it more "SOLID" than having that top class being injected with a middle class (bll) and having the middle class being injected with a bottom class (repository). Both ways reflect three classes, each with its own responsibility.

What you are dealing with is a matter of design. If you use repository class to only fetch data, no business process (as you should), then this class is actually part of you business flow, therefore should be injected into bll.

On the other hand, if repository class is engaged with business stuff it actually functions as a bll, in which case you have two bll classes injected in controller. Is it OK? to some degree, yes. But I prefer to have a single bll class, into which I would inject two (bll-)services. And probably each service should be injected with, well, a repository.